# Whether to automatically deduct fees after the free credit is used up

Tags: payment

I deleted all my projects and can’t contact the billing team, I just asked you, when my free credit limit expires, I don’t need it now Google Cloud platform Service, can the Google Cloud team automatically deduct the money from my credit card?

Answer (score 0):

When you use your  Google Cloud Platform free trial account and when the free trial period gets over you will not be charged automatically from your credit card to use the services.
You have to upgrade you google cloud platform account to a paid cloud billing account if you want to continue using GCP services.

for more details you can refer to the public documentation i have attached.

[end of free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#:%7E:text=End%20of%20the%20Free%20Trial,-The%20Free%20Trial&text=To%20continue%20using%20Google%20Cloud,data%20deletion%20on%20Google%20Cloud.)